# Install an app on android without SD card

Tags: applications, internal-storage, installation

How can one install an app on an android with no SD card?  I tried doing so with dropbox but I was unable to download the file.  I'm thinking astro file manager might let me but I've been unable to get that app installed.  Will that allow me to install an app with no sd card?

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: htc evo 4g from sprint

Comment: How much space do you have left on your phone's internal memory?

Answer (score 3):

One method to install an application without SD card is to use **ADB tool** (Android Debug Bridge). It's a tool for development. It will let you install your apk file using console.

What you have to do:

1. Install [ADB tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1474956) to your computer
2. Connect your device to your computer with a cable
3. Copy apk file you want to install to the folder where your ADB tool is. In this folder you have to find adb file.
4. Start your console - Terminal (on Linux) or Command Prompt (on Windows)
5. From your console you have to go to the folder in #3 - To do this use **cd command**
6. Type command **"adb devices"** - you have to see that your device is connected.
7. Type command **"adb install myApplication.apk"**

Comment: I do not believe it is necessary to download the entire android sdk, only the necessary *adb* tool, if using google keywords *adb drivers* is the keyword which will get a lot of hits... just saying :)

Comment: @t0mm13b, you're right, but I haven't tried it. [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1474956) I found a way to do it.

Comment: @t0mm13b, I updated my answer. Thanks for the good comment.

Comment: @t0mm13b `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`, `sudo dnf install android-tools` and `brew install android-platform-tools`